# Sage Pay Encryption for Request Data for Form Integration

Tags: encryption, opayo

I am working for an application which is build in VB.Net 2003 (Framework 2.0). I have to integrate SagePay using Form Integration method. Can anyone please provide me code by which I can encrypt the the request data. Request data sample is given below;

VendorTxCode=TxCode-1310917599-223087284&Amount=36.95&Currency=GBP&Description=description&CustomerName=Fname
Surname&CustomerEMail=customer@example.com&BillingSurname=Surname&BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line
1&BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A
1BL&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=447933000000&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname&DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress
Line 1&DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A
1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=447933000000&SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.com/failur
e

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at https://www.sagepaylabs.com/aes_vb.zip - this might point you in the right direction.